# Why do I have initialization problems in my code?

Tags: c, sdl-1.2

I'm a beginner in C language, first year in programming.
There is a problem where when I initialize an integer from a struct, it doesn't initialize, not only that but there are other problems that are happening in this code which I can not even begin to explain, I'll provide the struct and the code that is related with it, I use SDL 1.2 (due to project obligation in University).

[This is inside one of the ints that I have initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGY7m.png)

Header:

```
typedef struct{
    SDL_Surface *background;
    SDL_Surface *credits;
    SDL_Surface *quitbtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *creditsbtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *continuebtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *gitbtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *settingsbtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *gitbtn_s;
    SDL_Surface *leftarrow;
    SDL_Surface *rightarrow;
    SDL_Surface *btnreset;
    int isselected[5];
}menuitems;

typedef struct{
    SDL_Surface *gamebackground;
}gameitems;

typedef struct{
    SDL_Surface *pausemenu;
    SDL_Surface *resumebtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *settingsbtnreal[2];
    int selectedresume;
    int selectedsettingsreal;
}pauseitems;

typedef struct{
    SDL_Surface *settings;
    SDL_Surface *donebtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *fsbtn[3];
    int isselected[2];
}settingsitems;

typedef struct{
    Mix_Music *music;
    Mix_Chunk *scratch;
    TTF_Font *font;
    TTF_Font *fontBig;
    int volume;
}misc;
```

Code:

```
int load_files(menuitems *MI, pauseitems *PI, gameitems *GI, settingsitems *SI, misc *M)
{
   



    //Due to a problem, I am not able to initialize 


    MI->background = load_image("images/background.png");
    MI->credits = IMG_Load("images/credits.png");
    MI->quitbtn[0] = IMG_Load("images/exitbtn_u.png");
    MI->quitbtn[1] = IMG_Load("images/exitbtn_s.png");
    MI->creditsbtn[0] = IMG_Load("images/creditsbtn_u.png");
    MI->creditsbtn[1] = IMG_Load("images/creditsbtn_s.png");
    MI->continuebtn[0] = IMG_Load("images/continuebtn_u.png");
    MI->continuebtn[1] = IMG_Load("images/continuebtn_s.png");
    MI->gitbtn[0] = IMG_Load("images/gitbtn_u.png");
    MI->gitbtn[1] = IMG_Load("images/gitbtn_s.png");
    MI->settingsbtn[0] = IMG_Load("images/settingsbtn_u.png");
    MI->settingsbtn[1] = IMG_Load("images/settingsbtn_s.png");
    MI->btnreset = IMG_Load("images/btnreset.png");
    MI->isselected[0] = 0;
    MI->isselected[1] = 0;
    MI->isselected[2] = 0;
    MI->isselected[3] = 0;
    MI->isselected[4] = 0;

    GI->gamebackground = load_image("images/gamebackground.png");


    SI->settings = IMG_Load("images/settings.png");
    SI->donebtn[0] = IMG_Load("images/done_u.png");
    SI->donebtn[1] = IMG_Load("images/done_s.png");
    SI->fsbtn[0]= IMG_Load("images/fsbtn_u.png");
    SI->fsbtn[1] = IMG_Load("images/fsbtn_s1.png");
    SI->fsbtn[2] = IMG_Load("images/fsbtn_s2.png");
    SI->isselected[0] = 0;
    SI->isselected[1] = 0;

    

    PI->pausemenu = IMG_Load("images/pausemenu.png");
    PI->resumebtn[0] = IMG_Load("images/resumebtn_u.png");
    PI->resumebtn[1] = IMG_Load("images/resumebtn_s.png");
    PI->settingsbtnreal[0] = IMG_Load("images/settingsbtnreal_u.png");
    PI->settingsbtnreal[1] = IMG_Load("images/settingsbtnreal_s.png");

    M->music = Mix_LoadMUS("sounds/beat.mp3");
    M->scratch = Mix_LoadWAV("sounds/scratch.wav");
    M->font = TTF_OpenFont("fonts/Retro.ttf", 48);
    M->fontBig = TTF_OpenFont("fonts/Retro.ttf", 72);
    M->volume = 128;
    
    if (M->music == NULL || M->font == NULL || M->scratch == NULL || SI->settings == NULL || MI->background == NULL || MI->quitbtn[0] == NULL || MI->creditsbtn[0] == NULL || MI->continuebtn[0] == NULL || MI->gitbtn[0] == NULL || MI->settingsbtn[0] == NULL || MI->quitbtn[1] == NULL || MI->creditsbtn[1] == NULL || MI->continuebtn[1] == NULL || MI->gitbtn[1] == NULL || MI->settingsbtn[1] == NULL || SI->donebtn[1] == NULL || SI->donebtn[0] == NULL || GI->gamebackground == NULL || PI->pausemenu == NULL || PI->settingsbtnreal[1] == NULL || PI->settingsbtnreal[0] == NULL || PI->resumebtn[1] == NULL || PI->resumebtn[0] == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d\n", SI->isselected[0]);
    // If everything loaded fine
    return 1;
    
}
```

Sorry if this is unorganized as this is my first time posting here!
(Note that load_image is the same as IMG_Load)

Comment: Suggestion (lots of work): rather than `return 1;` for success and `return 0;` for failure do `return 0;` for success, `return 1;` for error with music, `return 2;` for error with font, ... so that you know what failed.

Comment: How do you call that function? What pointers do you provide?

Comment: @pmg  Indeed.  There's only one success result, there are many failure results. Returning `0` on success makes checking for *any* failure easy with a simple `if (returnValue)...`.  I've never figured out why that's not more widely understood.

Comment: Postponing the error checks to the end with the massive (and massively unmaintainable...) `if (M->music == NULL || M->font == NULL || (...) || PI->resumebtn[0] == NULL)` means you have no way to easily tell what failed.

Comment: @pmg  I understood, but my problem is not there, it is how when I initialized SI->isselected[0] to zero then it shows something else completely later.

Comment: also @Gerhardh, I called it using :
 if (load_files(&MI,&PI,&GI,&SI,&M) == 0)
  return 1;
In main

Comment: You really need to narrow down your problem - the shown output might also come from another `printf` and your shown function might just `return 0`, never reaching your `printf` there

Comment: @Odysseus, as I said, it reaches the printf, but it shows an int that is not equal to 0 (after initializing it to 0), I can take care of the if later but the problem is not there because it doesn't return 0

Comment: The symptoms suggest you have undefined behaviour somewhere in your code.  Are all pointers passed to `load_files` correctly initialized?  Without a [mcve] though all we can do is guess.

Comment: @G.M. They are not initialized, they get initialized inside the load_files function, Do I need to initialize them to NULL before they get passed?

Comment: @Jevro1337 The pointers I'm referring to are the ones passed to `load_files`: `MI`, `SI` etc.  You really need to show the code that sets up those variables and calls `load_files`.

Comment: That function call does not show anything. What are those variables you pass? How are they defined and what was assigned to them?

Comment: "if (load_files(&MI,&PI,&GI,&SI,&M) == 0) return 1;" How are `MI`, `PI`, etc defined? Are they plain structures or arrays (pointers)? If they're arrays (pointers) the call is wrong and shouldn't have the `&`; the call is ok if they're plain structures.

Answer (score 0):

Added new structure (Merged old existing SDL_Surface to this structure)

```
typedef struct{
    SDL_Surface *quitbtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *creditsbtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *continuebtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *gitbtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *settingsbtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *resumebtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *settingsbtnreal[2];
    SDL_Surface *donebtn[2];
    SDL_Surface *fsbtn[3];
    int isselected[9];
}btn;
```

Fixed my issue.